# Sample count problems

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, lighting, emission

I made realistic lightbulbs and I'm using them to light my scene however no matter how long I leave it to render or how High the settings this happens

[image: Render Result after 8 hours]

Here are my settings

[image: Here are my settings]

I've found that if I use simple spheres with emission for the lights it looks okay

[image: Normal Sphere lights]

But I want to use the bulbs

[image: Vertices of Bulbs]

edit-
I added thickness to the Glass and this happened

[image: Fail]

Thankyou so much for your help everyone!

the thickness wasn't the issue the render settings were here are the new settings

[image]

Comment: Not an expert on this, but first thing that seems like an obvious issue here is how you modeled the glass of the bulb, it looks like it has no thickness. If you didn't modeled the glass thickness, then its shader will tread it as a plain solid mass of glass instead of a hollow glass bulb.

Comment: thank you I will go try that now

Comment: I'm going to use solidify on the glass then render it overnight

Comment: The problem is your 'noise threshold'.  Lower to .001 or turn it off (or raise min samples) and use something reasonable for this many lights like 500-2000 samples.

Comment: I'll try that, thankyou for the help

Answer (score 1):

Allen was right on the money, the render settings were messed up. The solution was to disable the 'noise threshold' and to use 2000 samples.
The render time went from over 8 hours to under 45 mins.

After
[image]

before
[image]